# Missing DOMDocument in cli but not in apache

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, domdocument

There is a new EC2 amazon ubuntu server, where there was a php 5.5.9 installed.
I upgraded it to 5.6. I do not know if the error was before the updgrade, so perhaps this is not important anyway.
So the error: **DOMDocument can be used on apache, but not in cli.**
Class 'DOMDocument' not found.
The phpinfo shows the dom extension on apache but not on cli version, but the conf.d directories has the same ini files, and the php.ini files do not show any difference in this. What should I find and where.
Additional info: I've changed back to 5.5.9 and everything works fine.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the DOM extension cannot be enabled/disabled on run time. Does the CLI phpinfo show `--disable-dom` in the "Configure Command" section? (If you are using Linux, I guess it's also possible to have some PHP package or external library package missing from your system.)

Comment: There is not even a mention of dom in it.